# Getting error 403 when attempting to webscrape using python and jupyter notebook

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to webscrape some football stats. I am unsure why I am getting the Error 403. I have searched online and I think it has something to do with restricted access? Is there anyway to get past this?

Thank you!

[Here is what I have coded so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AA3rX.png)

I have tried using .session() or .text() but both have not seemed to work.

Comment: Please post as text not screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set your User-Agent request header to be something common. Without setting this it is very obvious that your request is not coming from a human and many websites will block requests without a common User-Agent.
Below code sets the User-Agent like your request is coming from a chrome browser for windows.

```
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}

r = requests.get(test_url, headers=headers)
```